# Require at least one file upload using plupload

Tags: jquery, validation, plupload

I am trying to find a way to make it mandatory that at least one file is uploaded when using plupload (https://www.plupload.com/) inside a form.

I do not see any options in plupload to require a file to be uploaded but, as plupload is not using a form field, I cannot use jQuery validate or HTML input required attribute which I am using on other form fields meaning the user can submit the form even if they have forgotten to upload a file.

I do not want the form to be submitted without at least one file being uploaded - I can check for this easily server side but I want to do this client side as well to improve the UX if possible.

Is it possible to make plupload work in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is way to implement this.

You can do something like this:

```
$("#upload-form").on('submit', function (e) {
    if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```